# Rspec: id exists in list of id's

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a test case where an id exists in the list of id's

I tried following but it doesnt work.

```
expect(response['products'][0]['ids'][0]['product_id'])
              .to include(product_1.id, product_2.id, product_3.id)
```

It fails everytime with error the expected id doesnt exist. 
e.g expected '123' to include '343' and '543'

but when i step through the code all id's are there so dont get why its looking in only in two `ids`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response['products'][0]['ids'][0]['product_id']` is a **`String`**: `"123"`.

[`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-include-3F) will return `true` here, for the following inputs: `""`, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"12"`, `"23"`, and `"123"` -- but that's clearly not what you're trying to test!

You wanted to check that this `product_id` is **in** that list; not that it **includes** the list.

---

This is a slightly unusual test to run, since your expectation is somewhat fuzzy.

If this is a `rails` application (i.e. you're using `ActiveSupport`), then you can make use of [`Object#in?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/in%3F) to write the test as follows:

```
expect(response['products'][0]['ids'][0]['product_id'])
  .to be_in(product_1.id, product_2.id, product_3.id)
```

Or if we're just using vanilla ruby then perhaps use `rspec`'s [`satisfy` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/satisfy-matcher):

```
expect(response['products'][0]['ids'][0]['product_id'])
  .to satisfy { |product_id| [product_1.id, product_2.id, product_3.id].include?(product_id) }
```

You may also be tempted to simply reverse the order of the arguments -- which technically works, but is a little confusing since the code seems like you're running assertions on the wrong object:

```
expect([product_1.id, product_2.id, product_3.id])
  .to include(response['products'][0]['ids'][0]['product_id'])
```

---

But back to the point of this being an "unusual test".

Presumably, you've written it this way because you're not certain which order the `id`s will be listed in - i.e. which product will actually be `response['products'][0]`.

The test would be even better if you either:

- *Made the order known* (but I cannot really advise how without seeing more detail), so that you don't need a fuzzy matcher in the first place, or
- Only have 1 `product` returned by the response in this test, or
- Change the test to read *all three* `product_id`s from the response, and then use the `match_array` matcher.